# Cannot keep nested tabs on mobile at the top - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to keep nested tabs at the top on mobile. The problem is that the margin (?) changes with the selected tab (screenshots below) and this causes the buttons changing positions.

[Selected first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S89hg.png)

[selected second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAs1d.png)

I use the following code to keep tabs at the top:

```
selector .e-n-tabs-heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: inherit;
}
```

How can I keep tabs "static"?
Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which illustrates your problem.